# Social Tables API: What is the difference between Venues, Bookable Spaces, and Room Diagrams?

Tags: social-tables

In various locations of the Social Tables API documentation (and within the application UI), I have seen reference to the following terms: Venues, Bookable Spaces, and Room Diagrams. Can you please provide an explanation for what each of these are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure!

Bookable Rooms are the actual floorplans of the rooms you are planning in.  For instance, if you are planning an event in a large Hotel in the Grand Ballroom, the Ballroom floorplan is represented in our system by a bookable room.

A venue are a generic term that is used, but if you're referring to a venue id:  Sometimes it refers to a bookable room, in these cases is is prepended with an S.  But Social Tables events can also be planned with a PDF or Image background if we don't have a floorplan CAD of the space you're planning in.

Diagrams are the actual end product of using our main diagramming product.  Think of it as a document with a collection of tables, chairs and other items.

Hope that helps.